# Create a Pull Request based on a commit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

Is it possible to create Pull Request based on a commit using Azure DevOps API?
For example, consider this is my source branch with the following commit history:

```
commit #5
commit #4
commit #3
commit #2
commit #1
```

Can I create a Pull Request such that Pull Request should ONLY include the following commits:

```
commit #3
commit #2
commit #1
```

Comment: I don't think you can. I think you have to move all head commits from your branch to another branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest Api (and manual creation) does not support commit selection... You may try to create a temporary branch and use PR from it.

To create a branch, try to use refs: [Update Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

The request body should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "refs/heads/my-temporary-branch",
    "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "newObjectId": "commit #3 ID"
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify. 1) How do I create temporary branch with commits up to commit #3 via Azure DevOps API? 2) What do oldObjectId and newObjectId mean?

Comment: Should I provide any filter in PATCH request?

Comment: @user989988 No, you do not need filters.

Comment: @user989988 I have posted wrong link to Patch request. Use Post instead Patch, check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Comment: @user989988 Can you add your request and body to your question? Additionally, the body is an array, I updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like I got it working. Quick question - can I perform this using Git Tag instead specifying commit?

Comment: @user989988 you can find your tag and use its objectId: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#refs-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch from any commit you'd like and then merge that branch via PR.

i.e.

```
git checkout commit3
git branch foo
git push foo
```

Then do a PR from the `foo` branch.

Comment: sorry - using AzureDevOps API?

Comment: Sure, you can create a branch using the Pushes API.